# Resource/Methods for "leveling" spells from the Harry Potter Universe?

Tags: homebrew, broomstix

I'm playing a homebrew version of "Broomstix" with my nephews and am looking for a resource that doesn't just list all the Harry Potter universe spells and their functions but also lists the approximate "level" of the spell (age at which it is learned at Hogwarts for the average student).  I don't have time to read the books again, but does anyone know of a resource (website) that does this?  Alternatively, can you suggest a rule of thumb for deciding how advanced a spell is?

Comment: Welcome back! Hop into chat and meet the new people if/when you have time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't yet found a complete list, but some fans appear to have gone to efforts to categorise some spells by grade.

- Potterdelpha has put together [this PDF](http://potterdelphia.com/decree24/standard_book_spells.pdf) of the Standard Book of Spells, grouped by grade.
- The Harry Potter Lexicon has an [Encyclopedia of Spells](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/magic/spells/spells.html). The [Charms](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/magic/charms.html) page alone has an apparently not very complete list of spells.

I've yet to find any resource that lists *when* people learned *what* spells. I imagine that could be sorted out by going through one of the several available lists of spells which also list who used them and in which books — something I won't be doing yet, unfortunately!